# Saving UILabel results into CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, save

I have a picker on a `ViewController` and the results print out on a label.  I am having a problem saving these results into `CoreData`, getting an error code

```
"[<__NSCFConstantString 0xf488> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key attribute.'.
```

Here is the code that prints out the label:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    mlabel.text= [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Here is the code that saves the label results to core data:

```
- (IBAction)editSaveButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    if (!currentCategory)
        self.currentCategory = (Entity *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];  

    [self.currentCategory setAttribute:[mlabel text]];  //This is the line causing the error

    NSError *error;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
       NSLog(@"Failed to add new category with error: %@", [error domain]); 

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Why is this causing an error?  Thank you in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no `attribute` property (thus `setAttribute`) defined on `Entity`.

You might want to check out this tutorial on Core Data: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm actually checking out a tutorial right now about protocols and delegates I think will help.